# Inline Assembly are not processed correctly

Tags: assembly, arm, inline-assembly

I have the following inline assembly. Can anyone see what is wrong with that:

```
#pragma thumb
void test(uint16_t bitLength)
{
    uint16_t testdata = 0xFF;
    
    asm volatile(                         
        "mov r5, %[sync_data]\n\t"          
        "strh r5, [%[test]]\n\t"    
        :  
        [test] "=r"(testdata)     
        :  [sync_data] "I"(0x1f) 
        : "r5", "memory");
    
}
#pragma arm
```

ERROR:

> printf(" - MMAR holds an invalid address.\n");  printf(" - BFAR holds
> an invalid address.\n");
> printf(" - IMPRECISERR Data bus error has occurred, but the return address in the stack is not related to the fault.\n");

It seems to me that this brackets are wrong. If I leave the outer brackets off from "str", I get a compiler error.

The above is an example. I want to write the register of some..

```
asm volatile(                    
        "str %[port_out], %[port_outclr]\n\t"    
        "strh %[tc3_zero], %[tc3_count] \n\t"    
        "strh %[etc3_bitlength], %[etc3_count]\n\t"  
        "str %[sync_data], %[sercom0_spi]\n\t"   
        "str %[value2], %[dma_ch_send_sd]\n\t"   
    :  [port_outclr] "=m"(*(uint32_t*)_PORT_GPIO_PORTB_OUTCLR),
         [tc3_count] "=m"(*(uint16_t*)_TC3_COUNT16_COUNT), 
         [etc3_count] "=m"(*(uint16_t*)_ETC3_COUNT16_CC_0),  
         [sercom0_spi] "=m"(*(uint32_t*)_SERCOM0_SPI_DATA),  
         [dma_ch_send_sd] "=m"(*(uint32_t*)_DMAC_CHANNEL_SEND_SD) 
    :  [sync_data] "r"((uint32_t)SYNC_DATA), 
         [port_out] "r"((uint32_t)1<<9), 
         [tc3_zero] "r"((uint16_t)0), 
         [etc3_bitlength] "r"((uint16_t)bitLength),
         [value2] "r"((uint32_t)2)
    :   "memory");
```

and for example sercom0_spi is

> #define _SERCOM0_SPI_DATA              (SERCOM0->SPI.DATA.reg) // uint32_t reg;

Comment: Please make a [mcve].  It's most likely because your constraints are incorrect.  But I can't tell without having even an error description.

Comment: The code you have interpretes `testdata` as an address and thus writes `0x1f` to address `0xff`.  The code can be replaced with `*(uint16_t*)0xff = 0x1f`.  Is this really what you want?

Comment: These are example data and not the real one. Yes, I want this.

Comment: @fuz It actually writes to an unspecified address because `testdata` is specified as an output.

Comment: @TimothyBaldwin Oh yes indeed.

Answer (score 1):

The rule of thumb with inline assembly is (a) avoid it if possible and if that fails (b) do as little as possible in inline assembly.  Since as we have already discussed you don't want to go for (a) despite this being a possibility, we should care at least for (b).  To this end, we

- avoid useless data moves
- move as much of the work as possible into operand generation

This reduces your code to

```
#pragma thumb
void test(uint16_t bitLength)
{
    uint16_t testdata = 0xFF;
    
    asm volatile(                                
        "strh %[syndata], %[test]\n\t"    
        : [test] "=m"(*(uint16_t*)testdata)     
        : [sync_data] "r"(0x1f));
    
}
#pragma arm
```

A clobber list is I believe not needed because nothing but outputs are written.

The error in your code above is that you use `testdata` as an input operand, despite declaring it to be an output operand.  This causes the compiler to omit initialising `testdata` as it expects your inline assembly to assign an initial value to it.  To fix this, we communicate our intent to the compiler by moving the memory access into operand generation.

In case you decide to go back to a pure C approach, this example can be written like this:

```
void test(uint16_t bitLength)
{
    *(volatile uint16_t *)0xff = 0x1f;
}
```

Note that as `0xff` is an odd address, a half word access is likely to fail unless your processor supports unaligned memory access.

Comment: Tnx, yes I know about this volatile but as I mentioned in another answer, the data are examples. BTW, it doesnt work. ERROR invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')

Comment: You sure that the 0xff is a problem? What you would do?

Comment: @makurisan Sorry, I forgot a dereference.  Note that `"=m"(testdata)` does something else.  It reduces your code to do `testdata = 0x1f` instead of `*(uint16_t*)testdata = 0x1f`.  Which of the two is what you want?  Perhaps you can explain in plain English (“prosa” as one would say in German) what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The `"memory"` clobber *could* be relevant to order this wrt. other stores done from pure C, like `atomic_signal_fence()`.  That could be relevant, especially given the `asm volatile` to essentially make this implement `*(volatile T*)address = value` instead of a plain assignment.

Comment: I added above the code which I want to implement in our mcu app. I want that the content of the reg has the value 0x1f. I have the inline already running with other inline but with the other code I have another problem.

Comment: @makurisan I understand now.  You might need an extra dereference in your code as the `_SERCOM0_SPI_DATA` etc. macros resolve to the address of the register as an integer (weird design choice) instead of the register itself.

Comment: @CORDES: No, I don't write plain c and not ASSEM. I compiled the function with 03 and the optimization is not exactly whtat we want. This is the reason that we write inline because with inline you can finegrain the code. Remember that 03 works not inside a function. Also we can not add another function because of latency.

Comment: @fuz: I dont know if we let it the way it is but at the moment it should work.